# how to customise color of EKEventEditView displayed by EKEventView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent, ekeventkit

**BACKGROUND**:

- I now can see how to customise the color of a EKEventView, which is an apple view that you can use to display a calendar event.  The code is per my post here: [is this code future proof for customising color of EKEventViews (code attached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883884/is-this-code-future-proof-for-customising-color-of-ekeventviews-code-attached)
- If this view is EDIT'able however the apple EKEventView class then shows a modal "EKEventEditView" view.

**QUESTION**:

- My question is how do I customise the color of EKEventEditView, for which the view wasn't trigged by my code, but rather by the apple code in the EKEventView.

**LINKS TO API**:

- EKEventViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html
- EKEventEditViewController  - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how Apple will respond to this code, but it works :)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(willShowController:) 
                                             name:@"UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

And selector method:

```
-(void)willShowController:(NSNotification*)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@ ", [sender description]);

    UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController*)[sender object];

    if ([controller isKindOfClass:EKEventEditViewController.class]){
        UITableViewController *rootController = (UITableViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)controller visibleViewController];

        UITableView *tv = (UITableView*)[rootController view];
        [tv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UIView *v = (UIView*)[[tv visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

There is only one string `UINavigationControllerWillShowViewControllerNotification` which you cannot find in SDK. But in this case it's only the string..
Hope this help you.

Comment: I use a part of your code from above reference in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure as I have never had to what you are asking, but since it subclass UIViewController try doing you color stuff on yourEventViewController.view.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean here - can you give a code example?  Where I'm not sure is that it's not my code launching the 2nd EDITable view, so because i'm not launching it I'm not sure where to put any code to grab a handle to the view and hence to use this to customise colors

Comment: Oh so the problem is that you can't find a way to reference the view?